# Why isn't the == operator working as expected with char arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

For some reason this snippet of code keeps returning 0 even though the token actually equals any specified characters of length 1--either 'M', 'T', 'W', 'R'. Any ideas?

```
int storeDay(char *token, struct Section s)
{
    int length = strlen(token);
    cout << "length of token: " << *token << " " << length << endl;

    if(length == 2)
    {
         if(token[0] == 'M' && token[1] == 'W')
         {
            s.constraints.days[0] = 1;
            s.constraints.days[2] = 1;
         }   
         else if(token[0] == 'T' && token[1] == 'R')
         {
            s.constraints.days[1] = 1;
            s.constraints.days[3] = 1;
         }
         else
             return 0;
    }
    else if(length == 1)
    {
         if(*token == 'M')
            s.constraints.days[0] = 1;
         else if(*token == 'T')
            s.constraints.days[1] = 1;
         else if(*token == 'W')
            s.constraints.days[2] = 1;
         else if(*token == 'R')
            s.constraints.days[3] = 1;
         else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't appear to return anything at all in the case of a match. Is there a missing return at the end?

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement at the end of the function, so the program has undefined behavior. Did you mean to return something?

Comment: Well the way I've had the function set up is that it only returns 0 if the formatting is off. It also works fine with tokens of length 2 above but only seems to be giving me trouble on length 1.

Comment: @DerrickTurk is right, [not all code paths return a value].

Comment: you don't have a proper return value for success cases. Please check if your compiler gives any warnings.

Comment: The return statement fixed it, thanks everyone. But that's weird still as to how it was working for the length 2 cases but not length 1 even with a return statement missing. So you need a return statement in all cases then?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Without return statement what do you think what will the function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems unclear. You are asking why it returns 0 in every case, but you do not have a return statement in every conditional path. It is more important to note whether or not the respective 'constraints' member is being set correctly. Of course, you won't be able to tell that from outside of the function because you're taking the Section object by value. Thereby, s is a copy of whatever you called storeDay with and you don't see the change in the original object.